# Insects on lemon plant

Tags: houseplants, insects, citrus, lemons

[image][image]See the insects on my lemon plant. It's eating out all the leaves of lemon plant. Same insects eating my curry leaves too.
Please suggest how to remove those.
[image]

Comment: The leaves seems to be also invaded by "leaf miners". You may try spraying neem oil to the leaves. Adding garlic and onion juice to the neem oil can also act as repellent.

Comment: If any one help comment what kind of insects are these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be [citrus swallowtail caterpillars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papilio_demodocus) (the butterflies are also known as Christmas butterflies). I imagine you can pick them off when you see them; they look pretty big. I'm not sure what else to suggest for control, offhand.

Comment: I did the same, pick them off or cut that perticluer branch, but believe me, they are so many and totally camofledged in branch.